# Play .ts video file on Android?

Tags: android, video, streaming-video, stagefright

I am pretty new at streaming video, so please bear with me.  :)

I am trying to port an m3u8 stream over from iPhone to Android.  Looking in the m3u8 feed, I found some .ts files.  From what I can tell, .ts files are, themselves, wrappers that contain the video stream (Elementary Stream).

Is it possible to play a .ts file in Android?  (The docs only list 3gp and mp4 as supported formats.)

Is there a way to extract the Elementary Stream and just process the video feed?  If that is in 3gp or mp4, I should be ok.

Will Stagefright handle .ts?  Is Stagefright even available?  I read that there are/were some problems with it.

(As a further caveat, I am not getting much help from my server guys.  They are pushing for a Flash player solution, including a proprietary player.  They will not provide me with a 3gp or an mp4 feed, but I'm hoping I can find that in the .ts file.)

I'm open to other suggestions.  Thanks for your patience with this newbie.  :)

Comment: If the server guys get there way, won't you have no iPhone video then?  There is no Flash player for iPhone.

Comment: We already have a separate feed for iPhone.

Comment: Hi user359519 :) Have you got any solution for playing .ts file? I want to do the same, please tell me if you have found any way.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard for that called HTTP Live Streaming. Android 3.0 supports this protocol to some extent which means you can pass the URL of the m3u8 playlist to the MediaPlayer and the player should be able to stream it over HTTP. Stagefright is bundled with Android 3.0.

You can browse its source code [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=media/libstagefright;h=64c419348b33ca9a57eb98bc5eaf677bf81aec56;hb=HEAD).

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735754/mediaplayer-framework-on-gingerbread-and-apples-http-live-streaming-support) thread might interest you: it summarizes support for HTTP Live Streaming.

Comment: According to that link, it looks like Apple's HTTP Live Streaming protocol is only supported in versions 2.3+.  However, as of 2/11/11, only 0.8% of users are using 2.3.  3.0 isn't even on the chart.  (See http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)  Is there a solution for 2.2?

Comment: I believe you will have to handle all of m3u8 playlist parsing and then playback of .ts files yourself. Maybe you can package stagefright code with your app. Or else, there is a 3rd party solution: NexPLayer by Nextream, SDK of which is public; you can try using that.

Comment: Did you able to play .ts files successfully? Where can I find NexPlayer SDK?

Comment: We contacted the owner of the Project but it never worked out. The latest MediaPlayer on newer platforms support Live Streaming. Does that not cater to your use-case?

Answer (score 2):

Android stagefright in Gingerbread and prior versions does not support playback of .ts (transport stream) or elementary stream. As you have rightly pointed out, it only supports MP4/3GP/MP3 file formats.

Comment: Android 3.0+ supports .ts, although with some problems.

Comment: True, But this answer was written at the time of Ginger bread release. Accordingly updated the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can play `.ts` video file in android by using NDK based project. Dolphine player is best open source player for android and also supports various formats of video.

You got the `.ts` link from `m3u` file. Now you can fetch binary data from `.ts` file and store this binary data in file, then play this file by using video player.