# android how to know the current ts file while streaming video using HLS

Tags: android

I used to ask the similar question before but no one answered.
So I still want to ask the similar question once again.

android how to know the current ts file while streaming video using HLS

For example, I want to know the ts now playing on my phone is stream00036.

I tried to find something useful in the logcat but nothing useful was found.

I tried to monitor the network stat on android but it didn't work either.

Can someone give me some hints about this ?
I really need to know the answer.

Comment: Can you check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156274/play-ts-video-file-on-android. I guess, this will give idea about your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am already being able to stream the video in HLS. I already had the m3u8 playlist and thus I don't need to play the ts file.
I just need to set the url as the location of the m3u8 file.

Comment: Try this : 

  VideoView videoview = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);        
  videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoview.setVideoURI(
  Uri.parse("http://pilatus.d1.comp.nus.edu.sg/~a0095695/video_repo/playlist.m3u8"));
  videoview.requestFocus();
  videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

  mp.start();
 
   }

});